# Pass String from thread to UI for display

Tags: multithreading, string, android-activity, handler

I am new to android and java programming. I am try to write a program to read data via bluetooth.

I trying to pass a String apple which I decipher from my bluetooth input data from my thread to my UI for display CalibrationActivity.

I am using handler for the passing.

I keep getting force quit. Can anyone please advice me how can I solve this problem.

Below is my entire code of my extend Thread.

```
package com.android.backend.data.bluetooth;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;

    import android.util.Log;


    import com.android.AutoActivity;
    import com.android.CalibrationActivity;

    import com.android.ui.UIManager;

    public class Connection extends Thread {

        final Connection tt = this;
        private final String TAG = "Connection"; // Class name for logging
        public boolean connected = false;
        public BluetoothSocket bSocket = null;
        public InputStream mmInStream = null;
        public OutputStream mmOutStream = null;
        public ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
        public BluetoothDevice currentDevice = null;
        public UIManager mgr;
        public boolean connectFailure = false;
        public boolean stopAutoConnect = false;
        public String type = null;
        public AutoActivity ff;

        public void bsocketcancel() {
            try {
                bSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public Connection(UIManager mgr, BluetoothDevice device, String message,
                String type) {
            this.mgr = mgr;
            currentDevice = device;
            this.message.add(message);
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Connection(UIManager mgr, BluetoothDevice device, ArrayList<String> message,
                String type) {
            this.mgr = mgr;
            currentDevice = device;
            this.message = message;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (type.compareToIgnoreCase("Manual") == 0) {

                Log.d("thread", "manual");
                if (!connected)
                    connect(currentDevice);

                if (bSocket != null){
                    for(String msg : message)
                        write(msg.getBytes());
                }

                mgr.hideConnectingProgressBox();

                if(connected){
                    mgr.connectedDialog();
                    System.out.println("Maunal connected");

                }

                Log.d("thread", "hideprogressBox");
                if (!connected)
                    mgr.showConnectionErrBox();

            } 

            if (type.compareToIgnoreCase("auto") == 0){
                Log.d("thread", "auto");
                stopConnection();
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {                      //Set to 5 second

                    if (!connected)
                        connect(currentDevice);

                    if (bSocket != null){
                        for(String msg : message)
                            write(msg.getBytes());
                    }

                    mgr.hideConnectingProgressBox();

                    Log.d("thread", "hideprogressBox");



                    if (!connected) {
                            mgr.connecting();
                        }

                    if (connected) {
                        mgr.connectedDialog();
                        bsocketcancel();
                        System.out.println("Auto connected");
                        //BluetoothManager.getInstance().disconnectAll(); // cut all connection after transmit
                        break;
                    }


                    if(stopAutoConnect){
                        mgr.cancelconnecting();  
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (type.compareToIgnoreCase("calibrate") == 0) {

                Log.d("thread", "calibrate");
                if (!connected)
                    connect(currentDevice);

                if (bSocket != null){
                    for(String msg : message)
                        write(msg.getBytes());
                }

                mgr.hideConnectingProgressBox();

                if(connected){
                    mgr.connectedDialog();
                    mgr.msgsent();      
                    System.out.println("Calibration connected");

                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int bytes;
                    String apple = "";

                    // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            // Read from the InputStream
                            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            

                            if ( bytes != -1){
                                while ((bytes==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
                                    apple = apple + "_" + new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                                }
                                apple = apple + new String(buffer, 0, bytes -1);
                                System.out.println("message " + apple); 


                                //pass data to UI CalibrationActivity
                                System.out.println("message out " + apple);
                                Message msga = mhandler.obtainMessage();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("key", apple);
                                msga.setData(bundle);
                                mhandler.sendMessage(msga); 
                            }       

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

                Log.d("thread", "hideprogressBox");
                if (!connected){
                    mgr.showConnectionErrBox();
                }
            } 

        }

        public void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
            currentDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            BluetoothManager.getInstance().getBluetoothAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // tmp = device
                // .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothManager.SerialPortServiceClass_UUID);
                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                        new Class[] { int.class });
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

                // } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
                // return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket connection failed", e);
                return;
            }

            bSocket = tmp;


            try {
                bSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Connection err", e1);
                connectFailure = true;
                return;
            }

            if (tmp != null) {
                // Get Input/output stream for Socket
                try {
                    mmInStream = bSocket.getInputStream();
                    mmOutStream = bSocket.getOutputStream();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
                    return;
                }
            }


            connected = true;
            connectFailure = false;
        }



        private Handler mhandler;


            public void read(){
                Log.i(TAG, "Read is running");

                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytes;
                String a = "";

                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            

                        if ( bytes != -1){
                            while ((bytes==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
                                a = a + new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                            }
                            a = a + new String(buffer, 0, bytes -1);
                            System.out.println("message " + a); 

                        }       

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                        break;
                    }

                }

            }




        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            if (mmOutStream != null) {
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message Sent");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
                }
            } else {
                //mgr.showConnectionErrBox();
            }
        }

        public void stopConnection() {
            try {
                if(bSocket != null)
                    bSocket.close();
                Log.e(TAG, "Connection closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getCurrentDevice() {
            return currentDevice;
        }

        public void setCurrentDevice(BluetoothDevice currentDevice) {
            this.currentDevice = currentDevice;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(ArrayList<String> message) {
            this.message = message;
        }


    }
```

Below is the affect portion

```
if(connected){
                mgr.connectedDialog();
                mgr.msgsent();      
                System.out.println("Calibration connected");

                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytes;
                String apple = "";

                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            

                        if ( bytes != -1){
                            while ((bytes==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
                                apple = apple + "_" + new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                            }
                            apple = apple + new String(buffer, 0, bytes -1);
                            System.out.println("message " + apple); 


                            //pass data to UI CalibrationActivity
                            System.out.println("message out " + apple);
                            Message msga = mhandler.obtainMessage();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("key", apple);
                            msga.setData(bundle);
                            mhandler.sendMessage(msga); 
                        }       

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Below is the code for my Calibration Activity

```
package com.android;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.android.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;
import com.android.backend.data.Playlist;
import com.android.backend.data.PlaylistManager;
import com.android.backend.data.SwitchBar;
import com.android.backend.data.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import com.android.backend.data.bluetooth.Connection;
import com.android.ui.UIManager;
import com.android.ui.playlist.PlaylistEntryList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

//public class CalibrationActivity extends Activity{
public class CalibrationActivity extends Activity  implements SimpleGestureListener{


    String gotBread;


        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {    switch(msg.what){

                case 2: 
                    Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();
                    gotBread = got.getString("key");

                    TextView aa = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.stringinput);
                    aa.setText(gotBread);




                    break;
             }
        }





    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //final MainActivity tt = this;

        String str = "";

        switch (direction) {

        //case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : this.finish();
        break;

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
        break;

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
        break;


        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
        break;

        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Do Nothing for now future development

    }



    private PlaylistManager playlistMgr;

    private PlaylistEntryList playlistView; // Data for listview, stores current
    // playlist in memory

    public String createdNameList; // Indicated the name of currently Name of
    // playlist that is being created

    public Dialog dialog_customizePL, dialog_createPL, dialog_customizePLms;    // Dialog boxes for
    // Playlist creation

    public UIManager uiMgr = new UIManager();

    public String CONNECTED_DEVICE_MAC;

    public String dialogboxtext;

    public Connection Conn;

    int i = 0;

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //BluetoothManager.getInstance().disconnectAll();
        unregisterReceiver(mRvcau);     //Sequence is important
        System.exit(0); // Kill off all thread to prevent connectiong lost popup
        // I use system because is a calibration so I want user not to leave the activity else cannot calibrate

    }


    protected void onResume() {  //restart bluetooth is accidently off it
        super.onResume();

        BluetoothManager.getInstance().init();
        BluetoothManager.getInstance().getBluetoothAdapter().enable();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED); // IntentFilter class is important to declare for below filter
        registerReceiver(mRvcau,filter); // mRvcau is the location of logic, filter is message identify by android

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED); // Future deveploment
        registerReceiver(mRvcau,filter); 

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED); // Future deveploment
        registerReceiver(mRvcau,filter);

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED); //    Future deveploment
        registerReceiver(mRvcau,filter);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remotedevicecalibration);



        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);      ////////////////// For Gesture 

        playlistMgr = PlaylistManager.getInstance();

        initUI();
        uiMgr.initPlayListUI(this);

    }


    int connect = 0; // Check connection
    int disconnect = 0; // Check disconnection
    int requestdisconnect = 0;
    int connectstatuschanges = 0;

    public BroadcastReceiver mRvcau = new BroadcastReceiver(){ // The new is instantiate the class **always read from the back
        // The line from the back is creating an instantiate of this class          
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //AutoActivity.this.finish();
                connect = 1;    // prevent activity from exiting
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED " + connect);  

            }
            else
            {
                connect = 0;
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED " + connect);
            }


            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {   //future development
                disconnect = 1;
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED " + disconnect);
            }
            else
            {
                disconnect = 0;
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED " + disconnect);
            }

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {   //future development
                requestdisconnect = 1;
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED " + requestdisconnect);
            }
            else
            {
                requestdisconnect = 0;
                System.out.println("ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED " + requestdisconnect);
            }

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) { //future development
                connectstatuschanges = 1;
                System.out.println("ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED " + connectstatuschanges);
            }
            else
            {
                connectstatuschanges = 0;
                System.out.println("ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED " + connectstatuschanges);
            }

        }
    };

    /**
     * Init layout component. Define Listener for Buttons and Dataset for
     * ListViews
     */
    @SuppressLint("ParserError")
    public void initUI() {


        Button Orange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalibrationOrange);  // new method on test using image
        Orange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                activiteSingleConnection(20);

            }
        });

        Button Blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalibrationBlue);  // new method on test using image icon to on the switch
        Blue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                activiteSingleConnection(21);

            }
        });

        Button Green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalibrationGreen);    // new method on test using image icon to on the switch
        Green.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                activiteSingleConnection(22);

            }
        });


        loadDataToMem();
    }


    public void activiteSingleConnection(int i) {

        BluetoothManager btMgr = BluetoothManager.getInstance();
        BluetoothDevice device = btMgr.getBluetoothAdapter().getRemoteDevice(
                CONNECTED_DEVICE_MAC);
        ArrayList<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(i == 20){
            msg.add("N");
        }

        if(i == 21){
            msg.add("J");
        }

        if(i == 22){
            msg.add("I");
        }

        CharSequence fruit = null;
        TextView aa = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.stringinput);
        aa.setText(fruit);

        btMgr.calibratesentMessage(uiMgr, device, msg);
    }

    public void loadDataToMem() {
        try {
            String str = "";
            //StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            FileInputStream input = this.openFileInput("bone.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    input));
            if (input != null) {
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] buff = str.split(",");
                    TextView topView = (TextView) this
                            .findViewById(R.id.remotedevicecalibrationtextview1);
                    TextView bottomView = (TextView) this
                            .findViewById(R.id.remotedevicecalibrationtextView2);
                    topView.setText("Name : " + buff[0]);
                    bottomView.setText("Mac : " + buff[2]);
                    this.CONNECTED_DEVICE_MAC = buff[2];
                    Log.d("loadDataToMem", str);
                }
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Below are my log cat error message

```
09-13 10:50:33.640: W/dalvikvm(2086): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-13 10:50:33.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
09-13 10:50:33.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 10:50:33.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.backend.data.bluetooth.Connection.run(Connection.java:196)
```

Hope someone can advice me how to solve. Thank You.